# Using React components in Vue

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, vuejs2

but have some React code done and want to use it like regular Vue component. I found package [Vuera](https://github.com/akxcv/vuera), but while trying to render react components I recive an error:

```
Error in file /src/components/MyReactComponent.jsx:4:2

The above error occurred in the <MyReactComponent> component:
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "TypeError: (0 , _vue.createTextVNode) is not a function"
TypeError: (0 , _vue.createTextVNode) is not a function
```

I'm using `Vue^2.6.11` and I made new project with `vue create .`, installed `react^17.0.2`, `react-dom^17.0.2` and `vuera^0.2.7` via `npm`.

[This is link to sandbox with this simple setup.](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-dhawan-v8x67?file=/src/App.vue)
What i'm doing wrong? Can someone show me the correct way?

Comment: I have tested something and if you remove the `<div>` tags and just return `'test'` you will see that it works... it seems there is something off related to JSX.

Answer (score 3):

I think what is going on is Vue doesn't know how to handle the JSX. But in general I would recommend sticking to only one framework or library and not trying to mix them.